# Dataset details presenting conflicting information

Tags: google-bigquery

Here are the dataset details for my streaming intraday table (currently also have the daily export on) -

Created Mar 17, 2024, 12:00:06 AM UTC+5

Last modified Mar 17, 2024, 1:01:16 PM UTC+5

Earliest entry time Mar 17, 2024, 1:00:10 PM UTC+5

Surely, the earliest entry time should coincide with "Created"?

Furthermore, when I run the following code:

```
select 

  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS hours,
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS minutes,
  EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS seconds
from 
`app.analytics_317927526.events_intraday_20240317`
where
event_timestamp=(select max(event_timestamp) from `app.analytics_317927526.events_intraday_20240317`
)
```

the result (shown below) does not coincide with the "Last modified" information.

Row hours   minutes seconds
1   16  47  38

Also, it seems that the "Last Modified" is updated every hour or so (last change occurred after 50 minutes), but the result of my query is showing the same results for the last 2 + hours